# Anonymous Type Parameters in ASP.NET MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone explain how ASP.NET MVC framework retrieve values from anonymous type parameters, such as `Html.ActionLink` where the parameter representing HTML attributes can be passed in as Anonymous type. I read it uses Reflection internally. I am looking for pseudocode or example to understand better.

Comment: You can go through the MVC [Source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases) and see for yourself

Answer (score 2):

It uses the [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) precious constructor which allows you to convert an anonymous object into a dictionary:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var anon = new { foo = "foo value", bar = "bar value" };
        IDictionary<string, object> values = new RouteValueDictionary(anon);
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as the implementation is concerned you may always take a look at the ASP.NET MVC source code but here are the relevant parts:

```
public class RouteValueDictionary : IDictionary<string, object>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, IEnumerable
{

    public RouteValueDictionary(object values)
    {
        this._dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        this.AddValues(values);
    }

    private void AddValues(object values)
    {
        if (values != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(values))
            {
                object obj2 = descriptor.GetValue(values);
                this.Add(descriptor.Name, obj2);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see it uses the `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` method to retrieve all properties of the anonymous object and their values afterwards.